# Cross domain post

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to do a cross sub domain post in asp.net mvc and as the post data ,i want to pass an object which will be used in the recieving action in controller .Can anyone suggest how i can do that?

There are two applications .Application 1 needs to open application2 in a separate browser and post some data to it which application 2 will use to render some stuff.Sorry for not being clear but they are actually under the same parent domain but different subdomains.Both the applications are mvc applications.

Comment: Sorry to ask but what are you trying to achieve, can you give more information? I'm reluctant to help you along the cross-domain posting route when there may be a less contentious solution.

Comment: There are two applications .Application 1 needs to open application2 in a separate browser and post some data to it which application 2 will use to render some stuff.Sorry for not being clear but they are actually under the same parent domain but different subdomains.Both the applications are mvc applications.

Answer (score 0):

If both sites are in your control, then you could have a service on the server that talks to both and send data via the service from one site to the other.

If one site is out of your control, then I'm not sure that cross domain posting is a good idea.